# How to create a POJO with list?

Tags: java, pojo

This is a structure that I want to create a POJO using list only.

```
{
    "firstobj": {
        "1": 1684.63,
        "2": 1684.63,
        "3": 1684.63,
        "4": 1684.63,
        "5": 1684.63
    },
    "secondobj": {
        "1": 5695.64,
        "2": 1684.63,
        "3": 1684.63,
        "4": 1684.63,
        "5": 1684.63
    },
    "thirdobj": {
        "1": 1684.63,
        "2": 1684.63,
        "3": 1684.63,
        "4": 1684.63,
        "5": 1684.63,
        "6": 1684.63,
        "7": 1684.63,
        "8": 1684.63,
        "9": 1684.63,
        "10": 1684.63
    },
    "fourthobj": {
        "1": 1684.63,
        "2": 1684.63,
        "3": 1684.63,
        "4": 1684.63,
        "5": 1684.63,
        "6": 1684.63,
        "7": 1684.63,
        "8": 1684.63,
        "9": 1684.63,
        "10": 1684.63
    }
}
```

This is a structure I am getting from an API call.I want to install it into DB.
Should i go with POJO or is there any other way to store into DB?
If i use POJO then, Should I create a different class? or can I do with one class?

Comment: nice, what stops you from doing so?

Comment: Do you have this as input and you'd like to parse it? How would the resulting list look like?

Comment: "This is not a JSON" validators aren't complaining about it.

Comment: What kind of POJO do you want to create?

Comment: That is in format JSON (https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and you could store it like JSON in the db.

Comment: This is a JSON Structure i am getting from an API call. Now i want to insert into DB for that i want to create a POJO class using a list coz there will be more values.